# Elixir and functional input validation

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to learn elixir(but mostly functional programming)

I am  implementing a very simple GenServer which basically wraps a list of entries. The maximum count of entries and the maximum size (in bytes) of each param is restricted(config file)

```
defmodule List do

    def init(_) do 
        {:ok, []}
    end

    def handle_call({:insert, param1, param2, param3}, from, list) do

        import Application

        param1_max_size = get_env(:app, ....)
        param2_max_size = get_env(:app, ....)
        param2_max_size = get_env(:app, ....)

        max_items_count = get_env(:app, ....)

        ## should be {:reply, {:error, :your_list_is_full}, list}  if list is full 

        ## should be {:reply, {:error, {:check_this_args_please, wrong_params_list}, list} if any param is wrong. wrong_params_list contains the offending params 

        ## should be {:reply, {:ok}, [{param1, param2, param3} | list ]} otherwise

    end

end
```

I know it seems easy but basically i'm trying to find an elegant functional way to do that. My head is procedural and i always end up in a "nested-if-else-hell" using = operator like if it were the C one.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way I know for validating multiple parameters is `Ecto` with its `changesets`. You might want to implement something very similar.

1. Create a datastructure that holds values and validation errors
2. Make all validation functions take that datastructure as first argument and return this datastructure to make it easy for piping. I am going to call it `changeset` the same way `Ecto` does.

The code could be something like this:

```
changeset = %{data: {param1, param2, param3}, errors: []}

def validate_param(changeset, number) do
  max_size = get_env(:app, :"param#{number}"
  if elem(changeset.data, number-1) < max_size do
    changeset
  else
    errors = [{:"param#{number}", elem(changeset.data, number-1)} | changeset.errors
    %{ changeset | errors: errors}
  end
end

validated_changeset = 
  changeset
  |> validate_param(1)
  |> validate_param(2)
  |> validate_param(3)

case validated_changeset.errors do
  [] -> {:reply, :ok, [changeset.data | list]}
  errors -> {:reply, errors, list}
end
```

In Elixir you can define an atom using quotes to contain special characters. If there are no special characters it is the same as without quotes:

```
iex(1)> :"a b"
:"a b"
iex(10)> :"ab"
:ab
```

Inside quotes you can use string interpolation so you can create generic `validate_param` using atom `:"param#{number}"`.

`elem` function is zero indexed, so we need to subtract 1 from `number`: `elem(changeset.data, number-1)`.

If there are no errors we are returning the changeset without any modifications.

Errors will have structure `{field_name, field_value}`. It should be easy to add `list` to the changeset and create one more validation function that checks list length and appends correct error.

You can also remove duplication in calling `validate_param` 3 times using `List.foldl`:

```
List.foldl([1, 2, 3], changeset, fn(number, changeset) -> validate_number(changeset, number) end)
```

or even shorter:

```
List.foldl([1, 2, 3], changeset, &validate_number(&2, &1))
```

The most important thing is the pattern of functions returning the same type as they take as first argument. It makes it easy to pipe things avoiding many nested `if` or `case` statements.